# Supported ECL connectors for 8.5

Tags: cme, content-manager, ecl, media-manager

Since Media Manager EOL is December 2020, my question is which ECL connectors are available and supported for 8.5?

I know that Bynder is. Are there any others?

Comment: Marko , I suggest to reach out to support and they will check internally get back to you with more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have contacted SDL customer support and checked with SDL internally.

As of this moment, only available ECL connector (if we decide not to create one) is for Bynder.

For Aprimo, minimum requirements are for 9.1, with the possibility of developing a connector for 8.5 also. If this happens, ill update the answer.